# count integers whose binary representations differ in exactly k positions from that of a given integer

Tags: algorithm, math, binary

Given four integers a ≤ b ≤ c and k, how do you count integers in [a, c] whose binary representations differ in exactly k positions from that of b?  a, b and c are about 30 bits long.

Comment: Are you familiar with dynammic programming?  I have some sketch of an algorithm that runs in O(log(C) * K), that is basically a more complicated version of the dp alg to count N choose K in time O(N * K), but that simultaneously walks the bitwise representation of b and c to handle the <= condition.

Comment: You might want to add that you need this count for all k, as you wrote in the comments below. This significantly changes the question (and the answers): some things are done much more efficiently all at once than one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just explicitly enumerate all values between `a` and `c`, checking how many bits differ for each value?  The technical term for this in information theory is `Hamming distance` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance

Comment: Since `a` and `c` are about 30 bits long. This means you could potentially have to enumerate of a billion numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to compute the count for a given a, b and c, and for all values of k, then I think your best bet is to iterate and count the number of bits in the xor'ed difference.

```
for (int i = a; i <= c; i++) {
    int d = i ^ b;
    int k = 0;
    while (d != 0) {
        k++;
        d &= (d - 1);
    }
    counts[k]++;
}
```

You can even parallellize this easily. You would need to keep a separate set of counts for each thread, and add them all up at the end to get the grand totals.

For a range of 1 billion numbers, the parallel version of this algorithm took 3.7 seconds on my machine.

EDIT: Actually, there is a way to get the counts without enumerating. Here's the basic idea for (a,b,c)=(17,25,29), or in binary (10001,11001,11101). First, notice that the range 11000-11011 contains b, and is also entirely contained in (a,c). So these 2^2 values, contribute choose(2,k) to each count. The next interval down is 10100-10111. The numbers in this range all have at least 2 bits different from b, so they contribute choose(2,k-2) to the kth count. The next interval down that is fully contained in (a,c) is 10010-10011, which contributes choose(1,k-1), and so on. You also have to count upwards.

2nd edit: Couldn't resist implementing this. Total time for 1 billion numbers: 0.004ms...

Answer (score 0):

Write the binary repr for b, flip k of the bits and check if it violates the bounds.  For a,b being 30 bits it shouldn't be prohibitive to write a shell script or a C program so long as k is reasonable.

Comment: In a worst case you would have to check C(30, 15) ≈ 155 million numbers, so this algorithm might not be feasible.

Comment: @Pteromys 155 million isn't actually that bad. With a reasonable constant, checking 155 million numbers should only take a second or two. (Seriously. It's true)

Comment: @quasiverse That's true, but I have to count them for all possible values of k within 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The total count of numbers which differ in exactly k positions from b and are written with at most 30 bits is `binomial(30, k)`. This number is the greatest when k = 15 and is `binomial(30, 15) = 155117520`, so this is better then enumarating from a to c, but still can be a lot. However if k is small that's the way - just enumerate all these numbers that differ in exactly k bits and check whether they are between a and c.
If that's too slow, then you should do it more intelligently - for example if a and c have the same highest bit, then this bit has to be set, so you can reduce the possibiities.